# Spring Security sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" is true even if the user isn't authenticated

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, authorization, thymeleaf

I am passing the auth object to the view, and the auth seems to be correct, both when i am loggedin and not:
This is part of my `HomeController`

```
    @GetMapping(value="")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        List<Film> films = filmService.findAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("films", films);
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth);
        if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            modelAndView.addObject("authorization", auth);
        }

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

`SecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailServiceImpl userService;

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                        "/registration**"
                ).permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

I have also added theThymelaf Spring Security dialect to the template, and these are my dependecies relative to spring security:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

i wanted to implement a badge for admin users:

```
    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Logged in as Admin</span></h5>
    </div>
```

and i have also tried another syntax of sort of the same functionality:

```
<div th:if="${authorization != null}">
  <p>Logged in as <span th:text="${authorization.principal.username}"/></p>
</div>
```

and it seems that the principal is a string (?) but authorization is not, which it tells me it isn't null either :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'username' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public or not valid?
```